# Should i implement a database or let operating system manage files(Media Library Application)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a media library application.(Like iTunes). Users can have thousands of media files.(Some files may be small like music and some files may be large like movies) Users should do operations like search,add,remove,change info etc. fast enough.  I'm trying to make a decision about how i store & retrive these files.

One way: Like itunes i can create a folder for library, in that folder i can create another folder for each artist, in each artist folder i can create a folder for each album and at last in album folder i can store music files. I'll create another file for storing information about music files(Album arts, lyrics and etc.) This way is easy to implement and manage. It will be fast also.

Second way: I can store everything in 1 file. I can use a database to store everything or i can use other methods like BinarySerialization and creating my own file type. This file type can have media file itself and it's information in it. I don't know if its possible. I don't know if it will be fast enough to extract a file and change smthng on it and storing it back.

Should i use itune's way or can you recommand another way to do it.

Comment: Apart from the question being too broad, files can be easily streamed, reading a blob from one big file can't. Video files can get *very* big, which makes it impossible to combine them in one big file. User will also hate the idea that their media is locked away in some proprietary file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do it the iTunes way. This gives users greater flexibility in copying, moving, and deleting songs without the use of your application.

Managing and indexing one large file could be cumbersome. And if the application can manage thousands of songs like you say, the file can grow large rather quickly.

I would keep a database to store meta data like song title, artist, and location on the disk. Don't use it to organize actual content. This is the way iTunes does it anyway. That way you can load a list of songs quickly without having to actually sift through the song's media content.

Answer (score 1):

Use a database to store the metadata about the files so you can index it by artist, album, genre, date, ... but store the binary data in a file system.

The database contains a reference to the files in the file system.

My own multi-zone music player also stores an MD5 hash of the file in the database so that it can find duplicates easily. Each entry in the database then has a list of disk locations instead of just one and it will playback if any are present.